flutter mobile_scanner: andriod build error
flutter mobile_scanner andriod build error.
After changing the minSdkVersion (19 to 21) in flutter.groovy.
Duplicate classes error:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10)
     Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.22)

Tried adding the following in andriod/build.gradle
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.projectname1"
    minSdkVersion 21
    compileSdkVersion 31
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

  }

} 

dependencies {
   implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
}

Error:
Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Error while evaluating property 'namespace' of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'.
      > Failed to calculate the value of property 'namespace'.
         > Manifest file does not exist: c:\mobile_scanner_example\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

